# Recover delete files in git after removing .git folder

Tags: git, git-bash

I am trying to push to a repository from an existing directory so I added all the files using

```
git add -A
```

but then i realized that i should not add the node modules folder, so i did a

```
git reset --hard
```

then I decided to add folders one by one and halfway through, i realized that i should have made the .gitignore file first so i decided to remove all the git relationships in my folder using

```
rm -rf .git
```

after i re-initialized the current folder using

```
git init
```

too many files are missing from the current directory. I don't have any backup of the project. Any idea on how i can recover the files?

Comment: Get `.git/` out of the trash

Comment: hi @Brian unfortunately it is not in my recycle bin..

Comment: `git pull master origin` to grab the current commit.  Always consider committing any major changes, then you can go back to `git log` and `git reset --hard [commit_ID]`.

Comment: Hi @SteveVentimiglia the files i was referring to was supposed to be my first commit in my repository. So i don't have  that reference.

Comment: @ChesterLim are you showing hidden files? dotfiles are generally considered system config and thus hidden from non-developer users and displaying them has to be turned on manually in most cases but I'm not super familiar with windows.

Comment: Also, if this was your first commit and you only deleted `.git/` I'm not sure what the issue is? I don't know how `--hard` works on the first commit but if you're just trying to unstage files in the future `git reset` works just fine.

Comment: @Brian yes, i'm showing all files including hidden. And yes, this will be my first commit and i'm also confused as to why my files were deleted. I wrote all the steps i did and suddenly my .API and .Data project is now empty.

Comment: I would imagine is has to do with using the `--hard` flag as it reverts everything to the previous commit (which didn't exist). I think you're out of luck here, sorry man.

Comment: In this scenario, the `--hard` reset would delete (from the index *and* worktree) any staged file.  Any unstaged (untracked) file might survive, oddly.

Comment: @Chester - Because, if you reset without a single commit, it goes back to square one.  A reset is used to move to your last commit (for the most part.)  Commits are made as nice stopping points (like a 'save' for your entire project), and then a push will make sure that the files are remote, so they can be pulled and recovered at any time on any system.

Comment: Thank you everyone for sharing your thoughts on this. I guess i'll redo everything then. Good thing i was still on POC stage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no backups, and either your OS doesn't do "soft deletes" (trash can, recycle bin, whatever) or you deleted in a way that bypasses them, then there is no reliable way to recover the work.

The `.git` directory contains *everything git knows* about your files, other than untracked files or changes in the working tree.  Removing `.git/` is almost never necessary and very dangerous, as this question unfortunately illustrates.  Other commands you used are also more aggressive/dangerous than what you needed, and the odds are you lost the working files pretty early in the process.  Sorry the news isn't better.

For future reference:

It is likely that the `reset --hard` is what deleted your working files.  You had done some adds and wanted to revert them, so a `mixed` reset (which is the default) would have been sufficient and would have left your working tree alone.  A hard reset restores your working tree to the committed state (along with the index).

After the reset you started doing `add`s again.  I guess when you had to start over a second time, you were worried that you might have git accumulating unwanted state.  It wasn't.  Another `mixed` reset would have been fine.  You can always use `git status` to make sure the index doesn't contain anything unexpected (and clear it out if so).

The only enduring record is what's in the database, and since you hadn't committed anything you weren't affecting the database yet.  Even if you had committed things you wanted to discard, as long as those things hadn't been shared with others there would be procedures for getting rid of them.

Generally git is very good at safeguarding your data, but it can't protect what you haven't committed; so asking it to use commands that are destructive toward the work tree, or nuking the repository and metadata (by deleting `.git/`) should only be done if you're *very sure* of why you're doing them.

Comment: Wow. This is very insightful. Guess i'll just have to accept that i will redo everything. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.